# Why isset is printing 1?

Tags: php, mysqli

Why is this line printing 1(true) and not the username variable?

```
$username = isset($_POST['username']);
$username = $connection->real_escape_string($username); 
print_r($username);
```

and how can I use `isset` to make a mysqli query?

Comment: its normal [`bool isset ( mixed $var [, mixed $... ] )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning 1(true) to $username. isset answer to: 'is that variable set?'.
try with :

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $username = $connection->real_escape_string($username);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
}
```

Normally we do this to check if post variable is set, and if it set, we assign the value to another variable which we will pass to the query, in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!